# Do I get more medals on Easy/Hard mode or does it matter?

Tags: lollipop-chainsaw

I'm never quite sure whether it's easier to gain currency in hard or easy mode in games until I learn. In Lollipop Chainsaw do I get more/less medals by playing on Easy mode vs hard mode? If so, how exactly are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience, gaining medals is easier on Easy mode, simply because Sparkle Hunting (killing 3+ enemies at once) is much easier on Easy mode.

While it did seem that each zombie gave more medals on Hard mode, the fact that on Easy mode almost any spin combo - for example, ***Maelstrom Spin*** (<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Square</kbd><kbd>Square</kbd>) or ***Holy Chainsaw*** (<kbd>Square</kbd><kbd>Square</kbd><kbd>Square</kbd><kbd>Square</kbd><kbd>Triangle</kbd><kbd>Triangle</kbd><kbd>Triangle</kbd>) - kills multiple enemies at once and earns you Sparkle Hunt bonuses makes up to that slight increase on medals on hard mode.